# Unity c# how to programmatically access device settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a game in Unity where I need to ask for permissions from player(IOS related). I cannot find a solution how to make on button click to open device settings. Any pointers?

I have tried to look for some documentation about this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestUserAuthorization.html for iOS as well as at this other link https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-permissions-in-unity.html for the common practices.

Answer (score 0):

This could be work also I used before, checking device access permissions for [iOS and Android](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1251197/check-device-access-permissions-ios-and-android.html)